# Vue router addRoutes deprecated but I want to add array of routes to Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router, vue-router4

This is my Main.js. I'm fetching routes from the database through an API call but Vue router version 4 deprecated `addRoutes` functionality. So now I can add only one route at a time. I don't want to add routes by iterating the routes/menu list. Please share your thoughts.

```
new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
    beforeMount() {
      if (this.menuList.length) {
        this.$router.addRoutes(this.menuList);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        menuList: "menuStore/menuList"
      })
    },
    
  }).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Where did you get that addRoute is deprecated? I didn't find mentioned it in docs https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/router.html#addroute

Comment: @Luckylooke for vue router 3, `router.addRoutes` is marked deprecated [here](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes). In 4 this method is no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

To add routes from my modules I use this simple code:

```
MyRoutes.forEach(function(route){
    router.addRoute(route);
})
```

Old code:

```
router.addRoutes(MyRoutes)
```

So you code should be something like:

```
this.menuList.forEach(function(route){
  this.$router.addRoute(route)
});
```

Comment: But this menu list will contain more than 10 menu items with more than 3 sub-menu items in each menu. How can we handle this?